# Protractor - Bamboo tests failing due to jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor, bamboo

When I run my protractor scripts locally with the DefaultTimeOut set , They run successfully, However when I run them on bamboo, they fail with error:  *Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL*

Here is my config setup

```html
exports.config = {

  allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
  directConnect: true,
  //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:9080/wd/hub',
framework: 'jasmine',
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 5000
},

  params: {
      defaultBrowserTimeOut: 30 * 1000
  },

  suites: {
    Login:['e2e/Source/Login/*.js'],
    }
   }
```

I am not sure where or how to fix this issue. Please help. Thanks

Comment: just increase the timeout

Comment: I did that and it still fails. Not sure what other workaround is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running protractor on Bamboo requires you to add your website url to the host entries , that way , Jasmine will not timeout.